# Need to add delete button and remove the selected tab only in bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on travelling website where I need bootstrap tabs in admin section. I've already done some parts like dynamic creating tab option.

> **Where I'm getting issue is when I'm pressing on delete button it works but it remove all the content instead of delete only the
>   selected tab only. Please help me to solve this issue.**

Here are the codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  
  //Remove rows from the form
  $('#itinerary_tab_content').on('click', '#deletetab', function(e){

    $(this).closest('#itinerary_tab_nav').remove();
    $(this).closest('#itinerary_tab_content').remove();

  });
});
```

```css
.btn-remove{
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -31px;
  right: -31px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-regular ">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="itinerary_tab_nav" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item " title="Itinerary Day - 1">
                        <a class="nav-link active py-2 px-3" id="tab-outline-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#outline-1" role="tab" aria-controls="outline-1" aria-selected="true">
                          Day#1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item " title="Itinerary Day - 2">
                        <a class="nav-link py-2 px-3" id="tab-outline-2" data-toggle="tab" href="#outline-2" role="tab" aria-controls="outline-2" aria-selected="true">
                          Day#2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item " title="Itinerary Day - 3">
                        <a class="nav-link  py-2 px-3" id="tab-outline-3" data-toggle="tab" href="#outline-3" role="tab" aria-controls="outline-3" aria-selected="true">
                          Day#3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content container" id="itinerary_tab_content">
                
                    <div class="tab-pane active fade show" id="outline-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-outline-1">
                      <div class="form-group row p-0 m-0"><div class="col-md-12 p-0 m-0 pt-5 pr-4"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove" id="deletetab" type="button"><i class="fas fa-times">X</i></button></div></div>
                    Form - 1  
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="outline-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-outline-2">
                      <div class="form-group row p-0 m-0"><div class="col-md-12 p-0 m-0 pt-5 pr-4"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove" id="deletetab" type="button"><i class="fas fa-times">X</i></button></div></div>
                    Form - 2  
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="outline-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-outline-3">
                      <div class="form-group row p-0 m-0"><div class="col-md-12 p-0 m-0 pt-5 pr-4"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove" id="deletetab" type="button"><i class="fas fa-times">X</i></button></div></div>
                    Form - 3 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.parentsUntil('#itinerary_tab_content')` in your jquery it will work's for dynamic

```
$(this).parentsUntil('#itinerary_tab_content').remove();
$('#itinerary_tab_nav > li > a.active').remove();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  
  //Remove rows from the form
  $('#itinerary_tab_content').on('click', '#deletetab', function(e){

    //$(this).closest('#itinerary_tab_nav').remove();
   // $(this).closest('#itinerary_tab_content').remove();

 $(this).parentsUntil('#itinerary_tab_content').remove();
 $('#itinerary_tab_nav > li > a.active').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-remove{
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -31px;
  right: -31px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-regular ">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="itinerary_tab_nav" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item " title="Itinerary Day - 1">
                        <a class="nav-link active py-2 px-3" id="tab-outline-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#outline-1" role="tab" aria-controls="outline-1" aria-selected="true">
                          Day#1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item " title="Itinerary Day - 2">
                        <a class="nav-link py-2 px-3" id="tab-outline-2" data-toggle="tab" href="#outline-2" role="tab" aria-controls="outline-2" aria-selected="true">
                          Day#2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item " title="Itinerary Day - 3">
                        <a class="nav-link  py-2 px-3" id="tab-outline-3" data-toggle="tab" href="#outline-3" role="tab" aria-controls="outline-3" aria-selected="true">
                          Day#3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content container" id="itinerary_tab_content">
                
                    <div class="tab-pane active fade show" id="outline-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-outline-1">
                      <div class="form-group row p-0 m-0">
                      <div class="col-md-12 p-0 m-0 pt-5 pr-4"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove" id="deletetab" type="button"><i class="fas fa-times">X</i></button></div></div>
                    Form - 1  
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="outline-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-outline-2">
                      <div class="form-group row p-0 m-0"><div class="col-md-12 p-0 m-0 pt-5 pr-4"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove" id="deletetab" type="button"><i class="fas fa-times">X</i></button></div></div>
                    Form - 2  
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="outline-3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-outline-3">
                      <div class="form-group row p-0 m-0"><div class="col-md-12 p-0 m-0 pt-5 pr-4"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-remove" id="deletetab" type="button"><i class="fas fa-times">X</i></button></div></div>
                    Form - 3 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Udhay for your help but instead of removing both tab's nav link and tab's content, It remove only the tab's content. But I need to remove both.

Comment: I added this line     $(this).parentsUntil('#itinerary_tab_nav').remove();   but it is not working. Any idea do you have? It'll be great help to me.

Comment: do you want to remove entire tab [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/dogoku/KdPdZ/2/)

Comment: yes, but only the selected tab when I press on the delete button

Comment: @PawanMall use this `$('#itinerary_tab_nav > li > a.active').remove();` in your jquery or check the updated answer